# Massive SQL query requires conversion to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq

I have an SQL query which I need to convert to LINQ. have spent a whole day on it, didn't have much luck tough. Here's the query

```
SELECT PC.PRSCLAIMID,
date_format(PC.DATEOFCLAIM, '%d/%m/%Y') as DateofClaim,
PC.PRSREFNO,
PC.FKARTISTID,
PC.FKSETLISTINFOID,
PC.STATUS,
PC.FROMDNN,
PC.EXPORTTYPE,
PC.FK_CATEGORYID,
A.LOGINNAME,
A.BANDNAME,
SMCATEGORIESTYPE.CATEGORYTYPE,
Count(SMLIVECLAIMS.LIVECLAIMSID) AS GIGCOUNT,
SMCATEGORIES.ID AS PROCESSEDID,
SMCATEGORIES.CATEGORY,
Ifnull(BC.FILENAME, '') AS BULKCLAIM_NAME
FROM SMARTISTDETAILS AS A
INNER JOIN SMPRSCLAIMS AS PC
ON A.ARTISTID = PC.FKARTISTID
INNER JOIN SMCATEGORIES
ON PC.FK_CATEGORYID = SMCATEGORIES.ID
INNER JOIN SMCATEGORIESTYPE
ON SMCATEGORIES.FK_CATEGORYTYPEID = SMCATEGORIESTYPE.ID
INNER JOIN SMPRSLIVECLAIMLINK
ON PC.PRSCLAIMID = SMPRSLIVECLAIMLINK.FKPRSCLAIMID
INNER JOIN SMLIVECLAIMS
ON SMPRSLIVECLAIMLINK.FKLIVECLAIMID = SMLIVECLAIMS.LIVECLAIMSID
LEFT OUTER JOIN BULKCLAIMDETAIL BCD
ON BCD.FKPRSCLAIMID = PC.PRSCLAIMID
LEFT OUTER JOIN BULKCLAIM BC
ON BC.ID_BULKCLAIM = BCD.ID_BULKCLAIM
WHERE ( PC.EXPORTTYPE > 0 )
AND ( A.DBID = 1 )
AND ( CASE
WHEN PC.EXPORTTYPE = 1
AND ( SMLIVECLAIMS.GIGDATE < Date_add(Now(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) ) THEN 0
ELSE 1
END = 1 )
GROUP BY PC.PRSCLAIMID
ORDER BY PC.DATEOFCLAIM DESC
```

what I did was the following conversion

```
    from e in
        (from artistData in dbContext.smartistdetails where artistData.DbId == 1 // SessionFacade.DBId
        join smprsclaimsData in dbContext.smprsclaims on artistData.ArtistID equals smprsclaimsData.fkArtistID join smCategoriesData in dbContext.smcategories on smprsclaimsData.FK_CategoryID equals smCategoriesData.Id join smCategoriesTypeData in dbContext.smcategoriestype on smCategoriesData.fk_CategoryTypeId equals smCategoriesTypeData.Id join smPrsLiveClaimsLinkData in dbContext.smprsliveclaimlink on smprsclaimsData.PRSClaimID equals smPrsLiveClaimsLinkData.fkPRSClaimID join smLiveClaimData in dbContext.smliveclaims on smPrsLiveClaimsLinkData.fkLiveClaimID equals smLiveClaimData.LiveclaimsID join bulkClaimDetailData in dbContext.bulkclaimdetail on smprsclaimsData.PRSClaimID equals bulkClaimDetailData.fkPRSClaimID into bulkClaimDetailJoined from bulkClaimDetailJoinedData in bulkClaimDetailJoined.DefaultIfEmpty() join bulkClaimData in dbContext.bulkclaim on bulkClaimDetailJoinedData.ID_BulkClaim equals bulkClaimData.ID_BulkClaim into bulkClaimJoined from bulkClaimJoinedData in bulkClaimJoined.DefaultIfEmpty() where smprsclaimsData.ExportType > 0 select new {
            PRSCLAIMID_Inner = smprsclaimsData.PRSClaimID,
            GigDate = smLiveClaimData.GigDate,
            DateofClaim = smprsclaimsData.DateofClaim,
            PRSREFNO = smprsclaimsData.PRSRefNo,
            FKARTISTID = smprsclaimsData.fkArtistID,
            FKSETLISTINFOID = smprsclaimsData.fkSetlistInfoID,
            STATUS = smprsclaimsData.Status,
            FROMDNN = smprsclaimsData.FromDNN,
            EXPORTTYPE = smprsclaimsData.ExportType,
            FK_CATEGORYID = smprsclaimsData.FK_CategoryID,
            LOGINNAME = artistData.LoginName,
            BANDNAME = artistData.BandName,
            CATEGORYTYPE = smCategoriesTypeData.CategoryType,
            LiveclaimsID = smLiveClaimData.LiveclaimsID,
            PROCESSEDID = smCategoriesData.Id,
            CATEGORY = smCategoriesData.Category,
            BULKCLAIM_NAME = bulkClaimJoinedData.FileName == null ? "" : bulkClaimJoinedData.FileName
        })
    where!(e.EXPORTTYPE == 1 && e.GigDate < oneYearOldDate)
    group e by e.PRSCLAIMID_Inner into groupedData
    select new {
        PRSCLAIMID_Outer = groupedData.Key,
        GIGCOUNT = groupedData.Count(),
        DateofClaim = groupedData.Select(a = > a.DateofClaim).FirstOrDefault(),
        PRSREFNO = groupedData.Select(a = > a.PRSREFNO).FirstOrDefault(),
        FKARTISTID = groupedData.Select(a = > a.FKARTISTID).FirstOrDefault(),
        FKSETLISTINFOID = groupedData.Select(a = > a.FKSETLISTINFOID).FirstOrDefault(),
        STATUS = groupedData.Select(a = > a.STATUS).FirstOrDefault(),
        FROMDNN = groupedData.Select(a = > a.FROMDNN).FirstOrDefault(),
        EXPORTTYPE = groupedData.Select(a = > a.EXPORTTYPE).FirstOrDefault(),
        FK_CATEGORYID = groupedData.Select(a = > a.FK_CATEGORYID).FirstOrDefault(),
        LOGINNAME = groupedData.Select(a = > a.LOGINNAME).FirstOrDefault(),
        BANDNAME = groupedData.Select(a = > a.BANDNAME).FirstOrDefault(),
        CATEGORYTYPE = groupedData.Select(a = > a.CATEGORYTYPE).FirstOrDefault(),
        PROCESSEDID = groupedData.Select(a = > a.PROCESSEDID).FirstOrDefault(),
        CATEGORY = groupedData.Select(a = > a.CATEGORY).FirstOrDefault(),
        BULKCLAIM_NAME = groupedData.Select(a = > a.BULKCLAIM_NAME).FirstOrDefault()
    }).OrderByDescending(a = > a.DateofClaim)
```

this conversion is working but it is too slow, then I create another conversion

```
from smprsclaimsData in dbContext.smprsclaims
group smprsclaimsData by new { smprsclaimsData.PRSClaimID, smprsclaimsData.fkArtistID, smprsclaimsData.FK_CategoryID } into smprsclaimsGroupedData
join artistData in dbContext.smartistdetails on smprsclaimsGroupedData.Key.fkArtistID equals artistData.ArtistID
let loginName = artistData.LoginName
let bandName = artistData.BandName
join smCategoriesData in dbContext.smcategories on smprsclaimsGroupedData.Key.FK_CategoryID equals smCategoriesData.Id
join smCategoriesTypeData in dbContext.smcategoriestype on smCategoriesData.fk_CategoryTypeId equals smCategoriesTypeData.Id
join smPrsLiveClaimsLinkData in dbContext.smprsliveclaimlink on smprsclaimsGroupedData.Key.PRSClaimID equals smPrsLiveClaimsLinkData.fkPRSClaimID
join smLiveClaimData in dbContext.smliveclaims on smPrsLiveClaimsLinkData.fkLiveClaimID equals smLiveClaimData.LiveclaimsID
join bulkClaimDetailData in dbContext.bulkclaimdetail on smprsclaimsGroupedData.Key.PRSClaimID equals bulkClaimDetailData.fkPRSClaimID into bulkClaimDetailJoined
from bulkClaimDetailJoinedData in bulkClaimDetailJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
join bulkClaimData in dbContext.bulkclaim on bulkClaimDetailJoinedData.ID_BulkClaim equals bulkClaimData.ID_BulkClaim into bulkClaimJoined
from bulkClaimJoinedData in bulkClaimJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
where smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.ExportType).FirstOrDefault() > 0 && artistData.DbId == 1
&& !(smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.ExportType).FirstOrDefault() == 1 && smLiveClaimData.GigDate < oneYearOldDate)
select new
{
PRSCLAIMID_Inner = 1,
GigDate = smLiveClaimData.GigDate,
DateofClaim = smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.DateofClaim),
PRSREFNO = smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.PRSRefNo),
FKARTISTID = smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.fkArtistID),
FKSETLISTINFOID = smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.fkSetlistInfoID),
STATUS = smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.Status),
FROMDNN = smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.FromDNN),
EXPORTTYPE = smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.ExportType),
FK_CATEGORYID = smprsclaimsGroupedData.Select(a => a.FK_CategoryID),
LOGINNAME = loginName,
BANDNAME = bandName,
CATEGORYTYPE = smCategoriesTypeData.CategoryType,
//GIGCOUNT = smprsclaimsGroupedData.Count(),
PROCESSEDID = smCategoriesData.Id,
CATEGORY = smCategoriesData.Category,
BULKCLAIM_NAME = bulkClaimJoinedData.FileName == null ? "" : bulkClaimJoinedData.FileName,
})
```

well this query is not fetching the expected data, i think it is due to multiple (group by)'s. I cannot post my DB Schema as well, the question is already too long to read. Any help or any suggestions on how to get around or work around this conversion.

Comment: Why does this need to be done?  It seems to me that it'd be easier just to create the query as a view in the database and create some entity off of the view or define the query as a model directly.. Is this an effort to define everything as models in order to be able to switch the database, I might see why you might undertake the effort, but this...I tend to think it's more trouble than its worth. ORMs are good for generating code for common situations; SQL is good for querying data when ORMs aren't good enough.

Comment: I'm not saying it cannot be translated to LINQ better, but if the best you can do is write something that looks a lot more complicated than the original SQL, I think the effort ought to be questioned.

Comment: the thing is I've been given a bug to solve in an existing system, the solution we made to solve is refactor the particular piece of code and in there are a particular point use LINQ instead of that query. If it was my own code, I'd've gone with a `view`

Comment: It is short-sighted to refactor to use Linq when you have code that is already there in SQl and may just need a tweak. You are increasing the risk of adding in a new bug. Linq is a tool and should not be used for every situation.

Comment: I need a solution or an alternative solution, what i don't need is criticism

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over thinking the LINQ a little, try the following LINQ.  The only thing I am not 100% sure about is the GIGCOUNT results so that might take a bit of fiddling with.

```
(
from A in SMARTISTDETAILS

join PC in SMPRSCLAIMS on A.ARTISTID equals PC.FKARTISTID
join categories in SMCATEGORIES on PC.FK_CATEGORYID equals categories.ID
join categoryType in SMCATEGORIESTYPE on categories.FK_CATEGORYTYPEID equals categoryType.ID
join link in SMPRSLIVECLAIMLINK on PC.PRSCLAIMID equals link.FKPRSCLAIMID
join liveClaims in SMLIVECLAIMS on link.FKLIVECLAIMID equals liveClaims.LIVECLAIMSID

join bulkDetail in BULKCLAIMDETAIL on PC.PRSCLAIMID equals bulkDetail.FKPRSCLAIMID into BULK_DETAILS
from BCD in BULK_DETAILS.DefaultIfEmpty()

join bulkClaim in BULKCLAIM on BCD.ID_BULKCLAIM equals bulkClaim.ID_BULKCLAIM into BULK_CLAIMS
from BC in BULK_CLAIMS.DefaultIfEmpty()

where
   ( PC.EXPORTTYPE > 0 )
   && ( A.DBID == 1 )
   && (
      PC.EXPORTTYPE == 1 && liveClaims.GIGDATE < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) ? 0 : 1
   ) == 1

orderby PC.DATEOFCLAIM descending

select new
{
   PC.PRSCLAIMID,
   DateofClaim = PC.DATEOFCLAIM,
   PC.PRSREFNO,
   PC.FKARTISTID,
   PC.FKLISTINFOID,
   PC.STATUS,
   PC.FROMDNN,
   PC.EXPORTTYPE,
   PC.FK_CATEGORYID,
   A.LOGINNAME,
   A.BANDNAME,
   categoryType.CATEGORYTYPE,

   // This gets me the correct count now
   GIGCOUNT = SMPRSLIVECLAIMLINK.Where(LINK => LINK.FKPRSCLAIMID == PC.PRSCLAIMID && (PC.EXPORTTYPE == 1 && LINK.FKLIVECLAIMIDSMLIVECLAIMS.GIGDATE < DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1) ? 0 : 1) == 1).Count(),

   PROCESSEDID = categories.ID,
   categories.CATEGORY,
   BULKCLAIM_NAME = BC.FILENAME ?? String.Empty
})
// Use distinct to get rid of duplicate rows
.Distinct()
.ToList()
.GroupBy(o => 
   o.PRSCLAIMID
)
```

EDIT:

I changed how I calculate the GIGCOUNT property, this should now return the correct number.  You will also want to use the Distinct() extension so that duplicate rows are removed.

Comment: My main problem is count, here I am not getting the count, is there a way to get over this count problem, in the 2nd query i selected the results the grouped, then again selected just for Count.